# Gradle in Jenkins cannot deploy to Nexus: internal ssl error

Tags: maven, ssl, jenkins, gradle, nexus

I am trying to get my Jenkins CI setup to deploy to Sonatype Nexus.

On my personal machine, running gradle upload runs fine, but when running it on Jenkins, I get this error (I added --stacktrace to get the whole error instead of just BUILD FAILED): http://pastebin.com/RPQQxZCg

Line 119 is what I believe to be the problem.

I have looked around the internet for hours but haven't found any resolutions to this problem.

My build.gradle is [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/HeroiCraft/Core/945c2a0e1219ac6ae255184e5bb7b9b24af35cd5/build.gradle). The jar builds fine, just doesn't deploy.

If you need any more information, please let me know!

Comment: Do the nexus.log files show any errors?

Comment: @rseddon doesn't look like it, no. http://pastebin.com/H7FGZtBF

Comment: If it makes a difference, nexus is running behind cloudflare and an apache reverse-proxy. It isn't https by default, but cloudflare does some stuff to make it https.